# Filter a CSV file to remove if Field 1 matches and the date/time in field 3 is less than 5 mins from the first field-1 match

Tags: linux, bash, awk, scripting, csv

Using a `bash` shell script on Ubuntu on a Raspberry Pi, I am trying to remove lines from a (comma separated) CSV list where { *Field 1 matches* AND *Field 3 is less than 5 mins (300 secs) from the first match of Field 1* }.

Here's a sample input file. I have annotated the desired output with # to explain why a line is kept or deleted. What I want is not annotation, but simply to remove the lines that say "delete".
The actual input and filtered output file would be something like this:

```
A11EEA,@N171WT,2021/03/06 12:37:25,700,0.1
A0FC0A,@N1624K,2021/03/06 13:37:33,1975,2.0
...et cetera
```

Input file with annotated desired output:

```
A11EEA,@N171WT,2021/03/06 12:37:25,700,0.1     # Keep - 1st occurrence of Field-1
A0FC0A,@N1624K,2021/03/06 13:37:33,1975,2.2    # Keep - 1st occurrence of Field-1
AB8C37,@AAL2386,2021/03/06 13:45:43,4500,1.3   # Keep - 1st occurrence of Field-1
A55325,@N442MG,2021/03/06 15:28:06,600,0.4     # Keep - 1st occurrence of Field-1
AB8C37,@AAL2386,2021/03/06 13:50:46,4500,1.5   # Keep - more than 5 mins from line 3
AB0ED6,@UAL1470,2021/03/06 13:51:23,4925,1.6   # Keep - 1st occurrence of Field-1
AB8C37,@AAL2386,2021/03/06 13:52:48,4500,1.7   # Delete - less than than 5 mins from line 5
AB0ED6,@UAL1470,2021/03/06 13:56:30,4925,1.8   # Keep - more than 5 mins from line 6
AB0ED6,@UAL1470,2021/03/06 13:56:40,4925,1.9   # Delete - less than than 5 mins from line 8
AB8C37,@AAL2386,2021/03/06 13:56:49,4500,1.0   # Delete - less than than 5 mins from line 5**

** Line 7 of the original record is not considered because it is slated for deletion
```

Ideally I'd like a solution that uses awk/sed/sort/uniq rather than recursively doing something like this:

```
while IFS= read -r line
do
   IFS=, read -ra record <<< "$line"
   # ... do a bunch of stuff
done < "inputfile.csv"
```

I tried this with `awk` but I got stuck quickly because of the complexity and potential recursion of the task.

Help? Pretty please?

Comment: So the line order is important - the first occurrence is never deleted, and when a line is deleted, it is not taken into account for all subsequent lines. Correct?

Comment: awk: An array with fields 1 and 3. For each line, check if the array contains occurrences of field 1 already and calculate the time differences. If any of the timestamps is less than 5 min apart, don't print the current line. Otherwise print it and store its fields in the array. Not quite trivial. The time difference function requires a little work, though not rocket science.

Comment: @berndtbausch both of your comments is what I'm looking, but somehow I'm stuck. Tnx

Comment: Awk seems to be a better tool for this job. Which implementation of Awk are you using? Can we use Gawk extensions like `mktime()`? If you're not sure, you can find out by typing `realpath "$(which awk)"` into your Raspberry Pi's shell. If the result is `/usr/bin/gawk` or something like that, it's Gawk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create  a function in `awk` to get the difference in seconds between two dates, and then you just store the last 'valid' date in an `awk` array indexed by the first field, so you can use it in the comparison, for example:

```
awk '
function getDateDifference(a,b) {
    gsub(/[:/]/, " ", a)
    startDate = mktime(a)
    gsub(/[:/]/, " ", b)
    endDate = mktime(b)
    return int(endDate - startDate)   
}

BEGIN { FS=OFS="," } 

dates[$1]=="" || (dates[$1]!="" && getDateDifference(dates [$1],$3) > 300){
    print $0;
    dates[$1] = $3
}' input.txt
```

Please note that before doing the comparison between dates you have to check if the indexed array value exists for a specific first field, just to assure the first occurrences are printed.

Comment: thank you - this does exactly what I needed it to do. And my apologies for the slow answer, your contribution is appreciated